# Prisma: Autoincrement based on a relation

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, prisma

There are two models,`Category` and `Post`. Each `Post` can only be in one `Category`.

I want to include a `category_based_id Int` field in `Post` where it basically `autoincrement`s based on what category it's in.

For example, there exists two categories: `foo` and `bar`. I'll add a post to `foo`, and that post will contain the `category_based_id` to `1`. I'll add another and `category_based_id` would be `2` for that post, and so on. However, if I were to add a post in `bar` instead, the `category_based_id` for that post would be `1`. Then if I add another, it would be `2` for the new post, and so on.

**How would I model this in Prisma?**

Comment: That is complicated and unneccessary. Don't do it at all. What are you really trying to achieve? There is probably a better way

Comment: Phrasing it as "Post" and "Category" wasn't the best way, so here's my actual use case on Discord: Each post is on a server. I want users to be able to reference the post using the server_based_id, not the global id. Global IDs aren't too good because you can reference a post from a different server.

Comment: To understand better, if there are multiple servers then you want the post to have a reference to each server, right? Example: If there are 5 servers then there should be 5 fields for the Post record?

Comment: No, a post should reference only the server containing it, so there should be only one server_based_id field in the Post table.